# geom_point and coord_polar - Warning for unknown aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know geom_point doesn't have mapping for ymin and ymax, but when I don't use them it doesn't give the figure I expect. Nevertheless when using ymin and ymax I get the figure I wish, but I get warning of "Ignoring unknown aesthetics: ymin, ymax". I can't figure out what should be done to avoid warning but getting the plot I wish.

Here is example dataset:

```
ab <- data.frame(a = seq(50,100,by=10), b=LETTERS[1:6])
```

Without ymin and ymax but not the figure I expect:

```
library("ggplot2")

ggplot(ab) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
    scale_y_reverse() +
  geom_rect(xmin=Inf, xmax = -Inf, ymin = 0 - 50, ymax = 0, fill="lightblue") +
  geom_rect(xmin=Inf, xmax = -Inf, ymin = 0 - 82, ymax = 0 - 50, fill="lightgreen") +
  geom_rect(xmin=Inf, xmax = -Inf, ymin = -100, ymax = 0 - 80, fill="darkgreen") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=1:6, size=1.5, color="white") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=c(50, 80, 100), size=0.1, color="white") +
  geom_point(aes(x=b, y=a),
             shape=21, fill="#FF9933", size=10, position="identity") +
  ggtitle("Test") +
  coord_polar() +
  theme(
    plot.title=element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 17, ),
    panel.background=element_rect(fill = c("white")),
    panel.grid=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major=element_line(size=2),
    panel.grid.minor.y=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=5),
    axis.text=element_text(size = 12, color = "black", face = "bold"),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks=element_blank())
```

with ymin and ymax in geom_point (the expected output with warning):

```
ggplot(ab) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
    scale_y_reverse() +
  geom_rect(xmin=Inf, xmax = -Inf, ymin = 0 - 50, ymax = 0, fill="lightblue") +
  geom_rect(xmin=Inf, xmax = -Inf, ymin = 0 - 82, ymax = 0 - 50, fill="lightgreen") +
  geom_rect(xmin=Inf, xmax = -Inf, ymin = -100, ymax = 0 - 80, fill="darkgreen") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=1:6, size=1.5, color="white") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=c(50, 80, 100), size=0.1, color="white") +
  geom_point(aes(x=b, y=a, ymin = 0, ymax = 100),
             shape=21, fill="#FF9933", size=10, position="identity") +
  ggtitle("Test") +
  coord_polar() +
  theme(
    plot.title=element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 17, ),
    panel.background=element_rect(fill = c("white")),
    panel.grid=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major=element_line(size=2),
    panel.grid.minor.y=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=5),
    axis.text=element_text(size = 12, color = "black", face = "bold"),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks=element_blank())
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why it's happening, but somehow adding `ymin=0` and `ymax=100` is ensuring that the y-scale goes from 100 to 0, even though `geom_point` doesn't take `ymax` or `ymin` aesthetics. If you remove those arguments and instead change `scale_y_reverse()` to `scale_y_reverse(limits=c(100,0))` you'll get the same result without the warning. That would be the "standard" way to set the y-axis range of the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ggplot2, the data that you're plotting is what determines the plot area unless you explicitly change the plot limits. Your `a` variable (which you're plotting on the y-axis) only covers the range from 50 to 100. Thus, unless you specify a different y range to use in the plot, that's all you're seeing by default. In short, the proper way to fix this is to pass the `limits` argument to the `scale_y_reverse` call -- this tells the plot to plot a different range than the range the data covers. It will look like:

```
scale_y_reverse(limits=c(100, 0))
```

(The 100 comes first because you're reversing your y-axis.)

If you add that change to your plot *without* the `ymin` and `ymax` arguments, you'll get the graph you expect.

Now, if `ymin` and `ymax` aren't mapped, why are they changing your plot? I think the reason is that geometries (like `geom_point`) don't remove aesthetic mappings that they don't understand. These mappings will get carried down to the layer, and if the layer understands the mappings, it will use them. That essentially "hacks" y-axis limits into the plot without specifying them the right way.